# type hinting super().__init__ call with concrete types

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, super, typechecking

Below are two class trees.
Each with a base class eating the base class of its neighbor class.

Once I derivate a concrete class, I also use the neighbor type as a dependency.
The code works as expected, however, the typechecker complains.
(I'm using pycharm)

I think the downcast from concrete to base type is okay, as the base class will always only work with the downcasted type and is not relying on the concrecte aspects of the concrete type.

```py
from typing import reveal_type


class BaseView:
    ...


class BaseController:
    def __init__(self, view: BaseView):
        self.view = view


class ConcreteView(BaseView):
    attr = "42"


class ConcreteController(BaseController):
    def __init__(self, view: ConcreteView):
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self):
        # gives an
        # Unresolved attribute reference 'attr' for class 'BaseView'
        # warning
        print(self.view.attr)
        # okay
        print(reveal_type(self.view))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    concrete_view = ConcreteView()
    controller = ConcreteController(concrete_view)
    controller.meth()
```

A half solution is to use factories that convince the typchecker
However, the linter still is not able to resolve.
Additional the factory pattern is not what I like and it makes things complicated just to satisfy the typchecker

```py
from typing import reveal_type, Callable


class BaseView:
    ...


class BaseController:
    def __init__(self, view_factory: Callable):
        self.view = view_factory()


class ConcreteView(BaseView):
    attr = "42"

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 10


class ConcreteController(BaseController):
    def __init__(self, view_factory: Callable[[], ConcreteView]):
        super().__init__(view_factory)

    def meth(self):
        # warning gone but lint still not working
        print(self.view.attr)

        print(self.view.b)
        # okay
        print(reveal_type(self.view))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    controller = ConcreteController(lambda: ConcreteView())
    controller.meth()
```

Additionally, I already played around with generic.

```py
from typing import reveal_type, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("")


class BaseView(Generic[T]):
    ...


class BaseController(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, view: T):
        self.view = view


class ConcreteView(BaseView):
    attr = "42"


class ConcreteController(BaseController):
    def __init__(self, view: BaseView[ConcreteView]):
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self):
        # no warning typchecker
        print(self.view.attr)
        # but no lint
        self.view
        # okay
        print(reveal_type(self.view))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    concrete_view = ConcreteView()
    controller = ConcreteController(concrete_view)
    controller.meth()
```

### Further inheritance

Based on the answer of mr_mo
To keep further inheritance on sub concrete class generic, I need to add a generic to the controller

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class BaseView:
    ...


class BaseController(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, view: T) -> None:
        self.view = view


class ConcreteView(BaseView):
    attr = "Concrete View"


class MoreConcreteView(ConcreteView):
    attr = "More concrete view"
    foo = "another attribute of more concrete view"


class ConcreteController(Generic[T], BaseController[T | ConcreteView]):
    def __init__(self, view: ConcreteView) -> None:
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self) -> None:
        print(self.view.attr)
        print(type(self.view))


class MoreConcreteController(Generic[T], ConcreteController[T | MoreConcreteView]):
    def __init__(self, view):
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self):
        print(self.view.foo)
        print(self.view.attr)
        print(type(self.view))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    concrete_view = ConcreteView()
    controller = ConcreteController(concrete_view)
    controller.meth()
    mcv = MoreConcreteView()
    mcc = MoreConcreteController(mcv)
    mcc.meth()
```

looks like I still have not understood the conecpt of generics in python...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last attempt is close. However, you weren't really using the generic to type the view in the concrete class.

#### Solution

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class BaseView:
    ...


class BaseController(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, view: T) -> None:
        self.view = view


class ConcreteView(BaseView):
    attr = "42"


class ConcreteController(BaseController[ConcreteView]):
    def __init__(self, view: ConcreteView) -> None:
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self) -> None:
        # no warning typchecker
        # now lint is working!
        print(self.view.attr)
        self.view
        # okay
        print(type(self.view))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    concrete_view = ConcreteView()
    controller = ConcreteController(concrete_view)
    controller.meth()
```

#### Notes

- Full type hinting includes return types for all methods
- Generic is a template you can provide the type in the concrete
- In concrete controller class, you implement the base controller with a concrete view. Thus, you can use the type in the `BaseController` template.
- In heritage (subclasses), if you type an input argument as the ancestor (base) of the class, you can still pass the class.
- In your example, the linting was the thing to address. Checked in PyCharm (builtin) and Pyre. Both supply linting correctly (having the `attr` attribute).

### Edit: generic subclass of a generic class

This is added due to the addition to the original question - how do I keep advanced implementations of generic classes, generic themselves.
More precisely, I'll try to TL;DR how generics are expected to be used according to official documentations in common linters (e.g. [MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html)).

> Generic types have one or more type parameters, which can be arbitrary types. For example, dict[int, str] has the type parameters int and str, and list[int] has a type parameter int.

- Generics are a way to pass create a type `A` that uses another type - `B` or `C`, without knowing which one in advance.
- Subclasses inherit their ancestor's attributes, method and types, etc.
- In the first example, `BaseController` is a Generic, that takes parameter type `T` and can use it across the class.
- `T` is a TypeVar, which means it's just a type. It can be bounded to a type to match any of it's subclasses or be exactly one of listed types (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)
- The `ConcreteController` subclass of `BaseController`, is using `[ConcreteView]` to tell the ancestor which type was eventually used.
- The type `ConcreteView` is checked against `T` and is a legit type (in this case, `T` can be any type, since nothing else is specified).

Additionally to the typing logic, we should consider how subclasses are being used. Since python basically allows you to do almost anything, there is not obligation of typing correctly. Running strict type checkers e.g. MyPy or Pyre can help with that.

Consider the following statements, assuming these are our rules of how things *should* be

- A base class implies to the subclass what **should** be implemented (see [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) about abstraction)
- A subclass uses the base class as a template and implements only what it should.
- There can be multiple implementation to the same base class
- If a class can handle a parent as an argument, I can handle the child, but not vise versa.
- This implies that the class can also handle the "grand child" (applying this rule twice).

Going with that spirit, one needs to decide if the base class can be a generic class, that can handle objects of type `BaseView` and all of it's childs. That is `BaseController`.

Then, `ConcreteController` can be an implementation that can handle `ConcreteView` and all of his childs, or even the parent. That really depends on what you are trying to achieve. For that to be generic, you need to make the `ConcreteController` generic again.

This is implemented in the following example:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class BaseView:
    ...


# We want to create a class typed with any subclass of BaseView
T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseView)


class BaseController(Generic[T]):  # this class is generic
    def __init__(self, view: T) -> None:  # on init, gets the type that was used by the subclass
        self.view = view


class ConcreteView(BaseView):  # here we want a new class (and type) - a concrete view, with attr
    attr = "42"


# again, we want a concrete implementation, that is generic to any subtype of this class
TC = TypeVar("TC", bound=ConcreteView)


# so we implement based controller, with a type of and subclass of concrete view
# but this class is also generic
class ConcreteController(Generic[TC], BaseController[TC]):
    def __init__(self, view: TC) -> None:
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self) -> None:
        # no warning typchecker
        # lint is working now!
        print(self.view.attr)
        print(self.view)
        # okay
        print(type(self.view))


class MoreConcreteView(ConcreteView):
    attr = "More concrete view"
    foo = "another attribute of more concrete view"


# finally, this is the most concrete implementation.
class MoreConcreteController(ConcreteController[MoreConcreteView]):
    def __init__(self, view: MoreConcreteView) -> None:
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self) -> None:
        # no warning typchecker
        # lint is working now!
        print(self.view.attr)  # linter finds attr
        print(self.view.foo)  # linter finds foo
        print(type(self.view))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    concrete_view = ConcreteView()
    controller = ConcreteController(concrete_view)
    controller.meth()
```

Comment: Thanks. After your answer it was clear. Now, how would I do a grandchild class? Need to add another Generic Para?

Comment: The type is generic. Just pass the subclass to the template; instead of `ConcreteView` you can pass `SubConcreteView`.

Comment: Not sure if im getting this right. Ill add a example to the question.

Comment: Yep you are missing a point. Will add further explanation in a moment.

Comment: @seimen see edit, hope it'll help you fill the gap. The thing is that this is very explicit typing. Most use-cases don't really need all the complicated typing if the design allows to do things implicitly. If typing gets messy, consider typing to keep it simple (design-wise).

Comment: Okay, I see, it was again near my mental model. Thanky very much. Helped me a lot to solve a quiet old and repeating problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, a straightforward application of generics makes this pass both mypy and pyright, and the revealed type is `ConcreteVeiw`:

```
import typing


class BaseView:
    pass


T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound=BaseView)


class BaseController(typing.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, view: T):
        self.view = view


class ConcreteView(BaseView):
    attr = "42"


class ConcreteController(BaseController[ConcreteView]):
    def __init__(self, view: ConcreteView):
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self) -> None:
        print(self.view.attr)
        typing.reveal_type(self.view)
```

This would probably be my first instinct, but note, the following version without generics that simply annotates `view: ConcreteView` in `ConcreteController` *also* works:

```
import typing


class BaseView:
    pass


class BaseController:
    def __init__(self, view: BaseView):
        self.view = view


class ConcreteView(BaseView):
    attr = "42"


class ConcreteController(BaseController):
    view: ConcreteView
    def __init__(self, view: ConcreteView):
        super().__init__(view)

    def meth(self) -> None:
        print(self.view.attr)
        typing.reveal_type(self.view)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    concrete_view = ConcreteView()
    controller = ConcreteController(concrete_view)
    controller.meth()
```

I don't have PyCharm on my current laptop. But I feel that if it is failing to infer `ConcreteView` in either of the above cases, then it may be time to switch editors. Or simply rely on `mypy` or `pyright` for static analysis. To be fair, without the explicit `view: ConcreteView`, pyright and mypy were failing and complaing that you were working with a `BaseView`. But it is always good to explicitly help the type inference in cases like these.

Comment: Until you annotate `view: ConcreteView` in a subclass, type checkers are not expected to narrow this type. It's not about insufficient inference power: without that annotation, why should `ConcreteController().view = SomeOtherView()` be forbidden? Just because `__init__` was restricted to accept some subset of possible subtypes?

Comment: @STerliakov well, mypy is inferring the type of `self.view` based on the type of the parameter `BaseView` (and the fact that the paramter is assigned to self.view). This is a convenience, an understandable one, but to me, it seems natural that people might then expect the type of the attribute has been narrowed to the type of the parameter in the subclass. To put it another way, suppose instead of calling `super().__init__(view)`, you re-implemented `__init__` to asign to `self.view`, then mypy and pyright will infer the type to be `ConcreteView` not `BaseView`